# How to link Solana and IPFS?

Tags: solana-program

I would like a user to upload an image. The proof of that particular user uploading this particular image would be put as a hash in a Solana account and the image would be stored in IPFS to reduce cost.

Do you know if someone has done that? Or if there is a way to store big images and just keep the proof in Solana?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this currently is with a different storage network that is just getting going but already highly usable, and built on Solana.

It is called Shadow Drive, it's being developed by GenesysGo.

https://docs.genesysgo.com/shadow/shadow-drive/before-you-begin
https://www.shadow.storage/genesysgo

There are *great* SDKs out already:
https://genesysgo.github.io/shadow-drive/
https://github.com/VegetarianOrc/shadow-drive-rust

A `HEAD` request to a file on Shadow Drive will return a hash value, which you could verify against some on-chain state.

Every file lives in a storage account hosted on Shadow Drive. The metadata for that storage account is stored as a Solana PDA, the owner of which is easily looked up. So answering "did address X upload file Y?" is doable in a dapp.

They offer both mutable and immutable storage, human-readable filenames. URLs are just `https://<host>/<storage-account>/<normal-filename>`.

Note: The file metadata (name, hash, etc) are *not* stored on Solana, they are instead stored on the Shadow Drive network which is AFAIK basically a Ceph instance with like a bunch of Solana-based security mechanisms baked into it. Furthermore, unlike IPFS, there is no content-based addressing, although I could be wrong there.